# SQL Select Based on SUBSTR of Another Query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, substr

I have a select command using substr which returns a list of numbers:

`select substr(numbers,76,8) as num from numtab;`

but when I try and run the following command to display records containing num in another table, I get 'single-row subquery returns more than one row'

```
select names from namtab where FK_number = (select substr(numbers,76,8) as num from numtab);
```

Comment: It think you just want `IN`, not `=`.

Comment: Thanks, this has worked.

Comment: In that case, I'd just accept Gordon's answer.

Comment: if you use "FK_number =" then you sould place a query that returns a value -not list of values-.

Answer (score 4):

Use `in`:

```
select names
from namtab
where FK_number in (select substr(numbers, 76, 8) as num from numtab);
```

I think the error is pretty clear . . . `numtab` has more than one row.